# Construction of games. Mechanism

Tags: java, game-engine

Usually games are created with infinite loop, which is built of two main methods:

```
while(true) {
  update();
  paint();
}
```

I wrote only 3 lines in java:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
List<? super HashMap<String, String>> list = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
long end = System.nanoTime();
```

Then I displayed time of execution such operation and I get:
1 ms, 323 us and 48 ns.

The game is fluent, if has at least 30 frames/seconds, so in 1 second, time for one frame: 33 ms.

If such simple operation as creating container took 3% of time for one frame, how it is possible to write fluent games? Only one operation took 3% of time, if application complicates, it is almost impossible to calculate and paint everything in 33 ms.

Usually in games `update()` is invoked more rarely than `paint()` ?

Comment: Profiling a loop involves "warming up" JIT, which can take 700000 iterations.  You cannot get meaningful performance numbers from this code.  You should do some Google research on Java Performance and Benchmarking

Comment: In short; don't worry about it. It's fast enough. You don't get any useful information from your test - you are just looking at noise.

Answer (score 2):

As Jim Garrison mentioned in the comments, when the JVM is starting-up things run slower. This is due to a number of factors including "Just in Time" compilation or JIT... profiling just a few lines of code is basically meaningless... the same lines of code run after an app has started may take a fraction of the time that they take if they are run in isolation.

Also, (slow) initialisation of big data structures is usually performed in its entirety before the start of a game update loop.

It is also possible to use multi-threading for background loading and init of resources... although often simply pre-loading everything during inter-level menu screens is acceptable.

Modern game loops are often a lot more complex than your example too:

For example, things such as mini-maps are often updating with a lower frequency or only being partially updated every frame, whilst physics often needs to run at a higher sample rate than the paint cycle.